# REST search API URI form

Tags: java, rest, search, naming

I'm implementing a search API which would allow searching on several types of objects in the system (clients, products etc.). Which form of URI would be preferable:

```
/clients/search
/products/search
...
```

or

```
/search/clients
/search/products
...
```

/clients, /products resources already exist for other purposes.

Edit:

I didn't think it would matter, but seems like it does, so - the search will probably be complex enough to require a POST instead of GET

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggestions looks quite reasonable: https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_tips_for_search so according to this:

```
/clients/search
/products/search
...
```

Tweeter uses non-consistent structure:

- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets
- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search

Splunk prefers notion of `search` being first: http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0.2/RESTAPI/RESTsearches .

So these examples show that there is no single best way to do this. I think it would be better to go with first example when you want to limit your query to apriori known resources. Otherwise use global search - `/search` with all else encoded as parameters (see Freebase API: https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search - they have their own language for querying ...).

Answer (score 2):

If it's a restful API you shouldn't need to use the word "search" in your URI as product is the resource and the HTTP method GET provides the verb. So you can do something like;

- `GET /product/998827727/` (retrieve product by id)
- `GET /product/?searchTerm=thingybob` (find product with search term)

That said, sometimes your search term is too complex so you need a utility resource so then you do something like `POST /product-search/` or `POST /product/search/` as product is the primary resource

Comment: Yes, it will probably be complex enough to require a POST. So you'd recommend /products/search in that case?

Comment: Yes I would if you feel it requires a POST. Some of the hardcore suggest you should do a POST to a search-filter resource which generates a hash or unique id for the search then do GET /product/search-filter/$filterId/ but this can be a bit chatty if you have high volume searches.

Comment: I'd also make sure to use the singular resource name, product and client vs. products and clients

Comment: Hmm maybe, but that's a system-wide convention by now and the API is already used (not much, but still), so I wouldn't want to change it. Besides, if you look up at the address bar of your browser you'll see .../questions/... :)

Comment: The only thing consistent about the adoption of REST is that the implementations will be inconsistent... BTW I recommend the RESTful Cookbook as a pattern catalogue for these kinds of decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are wrong IMHO.

Question: what i get if i send following HTTP requests to your service:

```
GET /clients/search
Host: service.org

GET /products/search
Host: service.org

GET /search/clients
Host: service.org

GET /search/products
Host: service.org
```

If /search and /products resources already exist, why not to reuse them and just send necessary query parameters when searching? for example:

```
GET /clients?gender=female&country=US
Host: service.org
```

If client requests for "/clients" service would respond with list of all clients, if URI includes query parameters service would respond with filtered results. I think there is zero value in creating such dedicated resources for searching.

P.S.
Twitter's URIs are awful.

Comment: Damn, you type faster than me!